# Should I not use Angular 2 Alpha in small-scale production projects?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I get it: **the API is going to change,** possibly in *dramatic* ways.

However, I make small apps for less than 10 customers each. I'm thinking that I can:

- choose a specific version and stick with it
- make lots of tests to check for compatibility with new releases

Also, given the projects are small, there's very little code to update when needed.

I realize that the Angular team is communicating the general readiness of their code in terms of availability for adoption from the general developer user-base.

I hear things like:

["Should You Use Angular 2.0 or 1.x?"](http://www.codelord.net/2015/06/27/should-you-use-angular-2-dot-0-or-1-dot-x/) =>
`"The executive summary: There’s no Angular 2 to use, so Angular 1 is still the way to go."`

And then I see videos [showing how to use it](https://egghead.io/series/angular-2-fundamentals). And I think to myself: with the above strategy of `choosing a specific version & sticking with it` + `doing very careful updates to new releases`, I don't see a very compelling reason ***not*** to. I mean, the only thing not to do would be not to go complaining to Angular whenever their changes inevitably break my code; **it's expected**. I'd be *disappointed* if it didn't break between now & then. That's part of the fun. Fix it and move on.

**Concerns:**

- **Security:** the only real concern that gives me pause is that some security issue might be in play. But then, that's almost always the case. After all, it is the world of cyber **in**security.

Comment: I'm considering changing the question to: `Are there any dangers to adopting Angular2 early in small-scale production projects, besides API changes?`

Comment: i would suggest you to start with `angular 2`, on paper there might be major differences... but till you will also be part of the journey and will learn the reasons why something changed and rationale behind it making you a better programmer in long term.. and given that its a small scale project you can afford to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular team can still make major changes in syntax and behaviour.

You can just try to use similiar approach with Angular 1.x, especially they [introduced .component in Angular 1.5](http://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method/).

So just work with directives and components, after Angular 2.0 release migration should be fairly easy.

Comment: +1 had heard about `component` being available in 1.5, however, I hadn't realized 1.5 was available yet (in any form)!

Comment: Math concern: there's going to be some difference either between `angular 1.5 – official 2` and `2 alpha – official 2`. I would suppose the difference is greater for the first than the second. With new projects, why not just start with 2 alpha, given the smaller delta?

Comment: It depends when your project will be deployed.
You can go with stable and well documented 1.x or try 2.0.
2.0 looks really nice, but without rich components library and questionable stability it can turn into a nightmare. It's just not ready for production yet.